# Dojo Function Parameter Order

Tags: javascript, parameters, dojo

When declaring a function using dojo, there appears to be a proper order for the parameters. This function header caused an error:

```
require(["dojo/dom",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dijit/form/Textarea",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojox/validate/web",
    "dojo/request",
    "dojo/domReady!"],
function(dom, Dialog, Form, TextBox, ValidationTextBox, TextArea, Button, request)
```

The execution of a request.post resulted in an undefined error. I then changed the order of the parks to this:

```
require(["dojo/dom",
    "dojo/request",
    "dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dijit/form/Textarea",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojox/validate/web",
    "dojo/domReady!"],
function(dom, request, Dialog, Form, TextBox, ValidationTextBox, TextArea, Button ){
```

By moving dojo/request and request earlier in the order, the error went away. I had the same problem in another script with different parms. Is there some documentation that explains how to order the parameters? Do dojo elements have to precede digit elements, dojo/domReady not withstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order should be the same as the order you maintain in the array of module names. This means that the following is correct:

```
require(["my/first", "my/second"], function(first, second) {
    ...
});
```

However, when you're working with modules that don't need a return value in the callback, they should be inserted **last**.

```
require(["my/first", "my/second", "dojo/domReady!"], function(first, second) {

});
```

If you don't maintain that order, for example in the next example, then you will get problems because the parameter will contain something that doesn't work.

```
require(["my/first", "dojo/domReady!", "my/second"], function(first, second) {
    // "second" doesn't work
});
```

In your first example you're importing `dojox/validate/web` before `dojo/request` but in your callback you have no parameter for `dojox/validate/web`. The result is simple, the parameter with the name `request` will contain the returned object of `dojox/validate/web` and not of `dojo/request`. Because of this, calling the `request` object will probably not work.

So what you need to remember is that you need to maintain the proper order **AND** that modules that have no return value (or a return value you don't need) should be placed **last**.

If you don't place them at the last position, then you have to specify a return value, for example, the next example will work:

```
require(["my/first", "dojo/domReady!", "my/second"], function(first, domReady, second) {
    ...
});
```

But this is a waste of memory since the `domReady` parameter will not contain any useful data (at least, if you don't use it).

Answer (score 1):

The order matters, as Dimitri says, but it's really the Asynchronous Module Definition ([AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)) specification that describes this: it's not a Dojo-specific thing.

If you use another AMD loader, such as [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), you'll see the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

when working with dojo, i think of the 
    require([""]) 
portion as parameter type for the parameters being passed into your function.

therefore,

```
require(["dojo/dom",
"dijit/Dialog",
"dijit/form/Form",
"dijit/form/TextBox",
"dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
"dijit/form/Textarea",
"dijit/form/Button",
"dojox/validate/web",
"dojo/request",
"dojo/domReady!"],
function(dom, Dialog, Form, TextBox, ValidationTextBox, TextArea, Button, request)
```

when you try to call

```
request.post
```

it's handling the 'request' parameter as if it is a type of 'dojox/validate/web' object.  if your function signature was:

```
function(dom, Dialog, form, TextBox, ValidationTextBox, TextArea, Button, validateWeb, request)
```

your code would have worked fine.

another analogy of sorts is to think of it along the lines of:

```
function("dojo/dom" dom, "dijit/Dialog" Dialog, "dijit/form/Form" Form, ..."dojo/request" request, string[] args0)
```

the above is obviously improper syntax, but it helps me to visualize it in that way as though it's a language such as java or .net where when writing a function, you declare the parameter types followed by the name of the parameter.